# Illegal account name?

Tags: discussion, support

I noticed there's somebody using an account named drupal (see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/3294/drupal), can we please block this, people will think this is some account associated with drupal.org.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think we should enforce some rule about what people can call their accounts. If the user tries to appear as the official Drupal account or be deceiving etc. we have moderator tools to help with that and you should then flag the user. Otherwise I don't think we should jump to conclusions about what people would think.

Comment: FWIW, there are quite a few users on Stack Overflow named "stackoverflow". I don't think any of them are in danger of causing serious confusion...